# How to calculate with matched number

Tags: perl

I have a file where every line starts with an integer and I want to subtract 2 from each of those numbers so that e.g.

```
2 foo
2 bar
3 foo
3 bar
```

becomes

```
0 foo
0 bar
1 foo
1 bar
```

I've tried

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+)/($1 - 2)/g' file   #-> '(2 - 2) foo'...
perl -pe 's/^(\d+)/add($1, -2)/g' file #-> 'add(2, -2) foo'...
```

Both don't work for me. I've read that Perl will interpret strings as numbers based on the context in which I use them, but I seem unable to make my intentions clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `e` modifier to **e**valuate the right side as an expression:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+)/$1 - 2/ge' file
```

I also subtract 2 to get your desired output.

Refer to [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

Comment: Thanks! Wrong subtrahend in question was my mistake, I'll fix it for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

```
perl -lane '$F[0] -= 2 if $F[0] =~ /^\d+$/; print "@F"' file
```

Also you are only doing one substitution per line, which is enforced by matching `^` - start of string (without //m), and don't really need the 'g' modifier - so maybe `s/^(\d+)\b/$1-2/e`.

Thanks to [peer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3014199/peer) for clarifying what seemed to be leading space in the example data.